# Transferring Control between Kernel Images

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2

As the title states, I currently have an existing bootloader/kernel image utilizing multiboot and GRUB. Appended to the end of my custom kernel image is the binary of Linux's bzImage.

During the boot process, I want to initially perform the actions associated with my custom bootloader/kernel, and then transfer the execution to the bzImage so that linux will boot **without** restarting the system or returning the GRUB menu.

There is little to no information about the topic, and any resources state methods of dual-booting, which is not my goal. Instead, I want to cram two kernels together (one being my own, custom, kernel image that is extremely basic), and have them execute sequentially, resulting in a linux kernel image being loaded, but not before my custom kernel/program has executed first.

Please let me know if you have any resources or information about the topic, thank you.

EDIT: and another part of the goal is to not have the two kernels loaded as separate entities, rather the linux bzImage is appended to the end of the custom kernel/program, and then transfer control by moving `eip` to the starting address of the bzImage.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal might be achievable using a procedure very similar to the [`kexec` system call.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) Note that the procedure will probably be more complex than you think, as modern computers tend to have multiple independent CPU cores.

Unless your initial kernel restricts itself to using just a single CPU core, your custom kernel needs to make sure the other cores are stopped before jumping to the new kernel, or you might end up with different cores running different kernels and stepping on each other.

[The Arch wiki has examples on use of `kexec`.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kexec)